# nested scopes in java

Tags: java, scope, nested

when we try out this code it doesn't work.

```
public class f {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    { // aussen 
            int a = 1;
            int b = 2; 
             { // innen
                    System.out.println(a);
                    // gibt 1 aus
                    int b = 3;     
                    System.out.println(b); // gibt 3 aus
            }       

    }
}
}
```

But our prof. says that in the inner scope the variable can be declared again, and that this inner declaration is used in the inner scope for the variable b. But in the internet on http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/08/scope.html
under "variable with the same name r takes places inside the inner scope" we found that our error is legitimate. Did this change in the last 9 years?

Comment: Also, I'm confused about what you're actually asking here - can you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: To my knowledge, this has not changed in Java since version 1.0, in fact, Java is very conservative about changes.

Comment: The answer to the last question is "because the language developers decided so." Note that this restriction does not apply to locals shadowing class variables. Honestly, you just need to circle back to your instructor and ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new variable of the same name in a nested scope is known as variable shadowing, and Java does allow it in several cases. Here's an example where `x` is declared four times in nested scopes:

```
class MyTest {
  String x = "class member";

  void foo() {
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    String x = "local variable";
    System.out.println("x = " + x);

    new Runnable() {
      String x = "inner class member";

      public void run() {
        System.out.println("x = " + x);
        String x = "inner local variable";
        System.out.println("x = " + x);
      }
    }.run();
  }
  public static void main(String[] list) {
    new test().foo();
  }
}
```

As you can see, it's already somewhat confusing. This can lead to difficult bugs when you accidentally use the wrong variable, even though the code is perfectly fine in a different scope and compiles without warnings.

For example, what should this code do?

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i); 
  }
}
```

- C++ would say "These should be two separate variables"
- JavaScript would say "These should both be the same variable"
- Java says "This is confusing, choose better names", and disallows shadowing local variables within a single function.

Answer (score 1):

This has not changed. Java was designed this way. 
Local variables cannot be shadowed by other variables defined in the same function.
The reason being consistency, all outer variables are also visible to the inner scope.

This is one case were Java works differently than for instance C and C++ which allows variables in the same function to shadow each other.